# Kafka Springboot - how to implement kafkaTemplate in onText correctly?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, websocket, spring-kafka

I am stream data live using http.Websockets and want to write the messages to Kafka.
However it seems like my implementation to send the messages is wrong.

Has somebody got an idea why?

My packages are structured like this:

```
- seismickafkaproducer
      - kafkaconfig 
      - streaming
```

This is how I have implemented the sending to kaka in my onMessage method:

```
@EnableKafka
public class WebSocketClient implements WebSocket.Listener {
    
    private final CountDownLatch latch;
    private final JsonParser parser;
    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    public WebSocketClient(CountDownLatch latch, JsonParser parser) { 
        this.latch = latch; 
        this.parser = parser;
    }
    
    public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket) {
            WebSocket.Listener.super.onOpen(webSocket);
    }

    public CompletionStage<?> onText(WebSocket webSocket, CharSequence data, boolean last, KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
        
        String message = data.toString();
        System.out.println("Message received, writing to kafka");
        kafkaTemplate.send("seismic", message);


        return WebSocket.Listener.super.onText(webSocket, data, last);
    }

    public void onError(WebSocket websocket, Throwable error) {
        System.out.println(websocket.toString());
        WebSocket.Listener.super.onError(websocket, error);
    }
}
```

This is my KafkaProducerConfig class in the kafkaconfig package:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServer;

    public Map<String, Object> producerConfig() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfig());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate(
        ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory
    ) {

        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
    } 
}
```

This is the kafkaTopicConfig class:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaTopicConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public NewTopic seismicTopic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("seismic").build();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Looks fine. What exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: I am not exactly getting an error. However when a new message arrives at my websocket I just get: "jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.WebSocketImpl@27efa2fd[uri=wss://www.seismicportal.eu/standing_order/websocket]" Instead of the "Message received". When I delete the Kafka code ist also prints message received. However my code was definitely able to create the right Kafka topic (I checked it in the Kafka container). The initiation of the "Kafka instance" in my code is thus likely right. Why am I not able to send messages? I have also built a python consumer to check for them but none were there.

Comment: Okay, the class for the properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
should be: Stringserializer.class but even after changing that nothing changed.

Comment: The `kafkaTemplate.send()` returns a `CompletableFuture` (3.0.x or later) or a `ListenableFuture` (2.9.x); you are discarding it; you should at least check the result.

Comment: 1) Kafka producers don't immediately send data unless you manually flush them 2) Kafka consumers start from the end of the topic, by default, so make sure you start the consumer before running any producer

Comment: I still only get: jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.WebSocketImpl@5d693348[uri=wss://www.seismicportal.eu/standing_order/websocket The return is not outprinted.

Comment: You're printing the websocket. You need to assign `kafkaTemplate.send("seismic", message)` result to a variable, then call `.get()` on its future, and then you can print its metadata, or any errors

Comment: The error seems to be when establishing a websocket connection:
java.net.sockets.error: connection reset 

Stacktrace:

java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(Unknown Source), java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source), java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube.readAvailable(Unknown Source), java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$InternalReadSubscription.read(Unknown Source), java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$SocketFlowTask.run(Unknown Source)]